# Liquibase MS SQL insert with special characters

Tags: java, sql-server, utf-8, sql-insert, liquibase

First of all the versions:

Liquibase: 4.2.2

MS SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)   Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
Collation: Latin1_General_CI_AS

MS SQL Driver: 8.4.1.jre11

I created the following table with a liquibase changelog on a ms sql server (and it is correctly created):

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">
   <changeSet author="m.author" id="833b698d-44c3-4c6e-aa61-0a9b48816a41">
       <createTable tableName="AB_COUNTRYINFO">
           <column name="ISO2" type="CHAR(2)">
               <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK_AB_COUNTRYINFO_ISO2"/>
           </column>
           <column name="ISO3" type="CHAR(3)">
               <constraints nullable="false"/>
           </column>
           <column name="NAME_LATIN" type="NVARCHAR(100)"/>
           <column name="NAME_NATIVE" type="NVARCHAR(100)"/>
           <column name="ADDR_FORMAT" type="NVARCHAR(50)"/>
           <column name="REQUIRED_FIELDS" type="NVARCHAR(50)"/>
           <column name="ZIP_REGEX" type="NVARCHAR(1000)"/>
           <column name="FLAG" type="LONGBLOB"/>
       </createTable>
   </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

In this table is all information about a country stored, eg. the name, the native name, or the flag.

Now two rows are inserted:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" 
                   xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" 
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">   
   <changeSet author="m.author" id="87ab2f68-920f-468f-8ff0-1cbf4c0f27dd">
                <delete tableName="AB_COUNTRYINFO">
            <where>name_latin = ?</where>
            <whereParams>
                <param value="Belarus"/>
            </whereParams>
        </delete>
        
        <insert tableName="AB_COUNTRYINFO">
            <column name="ISO2" value="BY"/>
            <column name="ISO3" value="BLR"/>
            <column name="NAME_LATIN" value="Belarus"/>
            <column name="NAME_NATIVE" value="Белару́сь"/>
            <column name="ADDR_FORMAT" value="%S%n%Z %C%n%A%n%O%n%N"/>
            <column name="REQUIRED_FIELDS" value="AC"/>
            <column name="ZIP_REGEX" value="\d{6}"/>
            <column name="FLAG" valueBlobFile="basic/init/data/pathXY/ab_countryinfo/ChangesLobFile/blob/BY.svg"/>
        </insert>
        
        <insert tableName="AB_COUNTRYINFO">
            <column name="ISO2" value="XX"/>
            <column name="ISO3" value="XXX"/>
            <column name="NAME_LATIN" value="Belarus"/>
            <column name="NAME_NATIVE" value="Белару́сь"/>
            <column name="ADDR_FORMAT" value="%S%n%Z %C%n%A%n%O%n%N"/>
            <column name="REQUIRED_FIELDS" value="AC"/>
            <column name="ZIP_REGEX" value="\d{6}"/>
        </insert>
   </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Now I executed following command:

`SELECT ISO2, NAME_NATIVE FROM AB_COUNTRYINFO WHERE NAME_LATIN='Belarus'`

There are now two different NAME_NATIVE-results:
The second row (with ISO2-Value = XX) has the correct name_native (Белару́сь), but the first row (with ISO2-Value = BY) has a wrong name_native (???? ????), it looks like the special characters cannot be stored. If I use only normal characters, everything works fine.

If I remove`"<column name="FLAG" valueBlobFile="basic/init/data/pathXY/ab_countryinfo/ChangesLobFile/blob/BY.svg"/>` of the first insert, everything works fine.

Question: Why makes it a difference in the value of a column on an insert if another's column-value is present? What is a possible solution?

This phanomen is only in a project of a customer. I tried to reproduce it with a similar environment, but it wasn't possible to reproduce it.

Comment: [`LONGBLOB` in _MS SQL Server_](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/2203/mysql-to-sql-server-data-type-comparisons/)?

Comment: @JosefZ This is mapped by liquibase to VARBINARY(2147483647)